# How to submit form with angular in mvc?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have form:

```
 <form ng-controller="accountContentController" name="editUserForm" action="PersonalInformation" method="post">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ZipCode, new { id = "zipCode", name = "zipCode", @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "5", @required = "required", ng_model = "zipCode", ng_pattern = @"/[0-9]{5}$/" })
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id = "password", name = "password", ng_model = "password", @class = "form-control", @required = "required"})
    <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn-block secondary-button save-changes" value="@Translator.Translate("SAVE_CHANGES")">
</form>
```

i have controller in mvc:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult PersonalInformation(PersonalInformationModel model)
   {
       return View(model);
   }
```

How can i submit form to send data from view to controller with angular?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need a custom ajax submit function in your submit button.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="submit(editUserForm)">@Translator.Translate("SAVE_CHANGES")</button>
```

Then handle submit in your controller

```
$scope.submit = function(form) {
    // client side error checking
    if (form.$invalid) {
        // do something and return
    }

    // pack all parameter to match with keys in your model
    var model = {
        ZipCode: $scope.zipcode,
        Password: $scope.password
    }

    // send to your controller
    $http.post('/className/PersonalInformation', {model: model})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            // handle success here
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            // handle error here
        });
}
```

Then in your controller change ActionResult to JsonResult

```
public JsonResult PersonalInformation(PersonalInformationModel model)
{
    // do something with model
    var result = doSomething(model);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: it not trigger my mvc controller

Comment: did you change the className to your mvc controller name?

Comment: Yes ... i added alert on start of function and its trigger but controller is not trigger

Comment: Can you check your browser developer console network tab and see whether the request is sent correctly?

Comment: when i watch on fiddler i dont see any request that is sent

Comment: You'll need to inject $http on your angular controller, if you haven't already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81963/discussion-between-none-and-icycool).